# Pre link ordering of directives not obeyed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wish to understand the order of prelink in nested directives. I have the following html in place:

```
<directive-a ng-model="model1" directive-b="true">

</directive-a>

<ssn-widget ng-model="abc" hc-initial="true">

</ssn-widget>
```

Following in the associated javascript:

```
angular.module("directiveTest", [])
.directive("directiveA", function(){
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    restrict: "E",
    compile: function(){
      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
          alert("in pre of directiveA");
        }
      }

    }
  };
})
.directive("directiveB", function(){
  return {
    require : "ngModel",
    restrict: "A",
    compile: function(){
      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
          alert("in pre of directiveB");
        }
      }

    }
  };
})
.directive("ssnWidget", function(){
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    restrict: "E",
    compile: function(){
      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
          alert("in pre of ssnWidget");
        }
      }

    }
  };
})
.directive("hcInitial", function(){
  return {
    require : "ngModel",
    restrict: "A",
    compile: function(){
      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
          alert("in pre of hcInitial");
        }
      }

    }
  };
});
```

I have the impression that pre link functions run from parent to child. Hence, pre link functions of `directive-a` and `ssn-widget` should run before `directive-b` and `hc-initial` respectively. However, this is true for `directive-a` and `directive-b` pair but not for `ssn-widget` and `hc-initial`. I am unable to understand this behaviour. Following is the plunker:

[Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/wUvtfbjQinIOad5b4N29/preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

directives are not nested in your example, they are on the same level/tag

nested directives are children of other directives :

```
<dir-a>
  <dir-b></dir-b>
</dir-a>
```

I didn't know that but, for directive on the same level, angular compile them in alphabetical order. If you rename ssnWidget to gsnWidget, it will be compiled before hcInitial

The best way to change that behaviour is to use the **priority** property in the DDO.

```
.directive("ssnWidget", function(){
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    restrict: "E",
    priority: 2,
    compile: function(){
      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
          alert("in pre of ssnWidget");
        }
      }

    }
  };
})
```

Comment: Alphabetical order is a complete surprise to me. :)